Loading Java Application into Oracle Database with dependencies
Basic Info: I've created an java application that is an OPC UA client with the help of Eclipse milo packages (org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk and org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.stack.core).
The project is a Maven Project (as well as other dependencies).
I'm using Java 1.8 when generating jar, because I have Oracle 19c database with the same java version.
What I want:
I just want to be able to run java application on Oracle Database.
What I tried::

I successfully managed to run application in windows environment by exporting project to Runnable jar.

I tried to import that jar to Oracle Database using loadjava tool:
loadjava -user user/password@db OPCUA.jar


I got errors:

Error while creating class META-INF/versions/9/module-info
ORA-29509: incorrectly constructed binary Java class definition ORA-06512: at line 1
Error while creating class module-info
ORA-29509: incorrectly constructed binary Java class definition ORA-06512: at line 1
The following operations failed
class META-INF/versions/9/module-info: creation (createFailed)
class module-info: creation (createFailed) exiting  : Failures occurred during processing


After that I excluded module-info and META-INF from maven build adding necessary code to pom.xml however, it didn't help.
After that I changed way of generating JAR's in Eclipse from Extract required libraries into generated Jar to Package required libraries into generated Jar
I tried to import it with loadjava tool but got plenty of exceptions


Error while determining classes contained in
org/eclipse/milo/opcua/stack/core/serialization/binary/BinaryDecoderTest.java
Exception oracle.aurora.sqljdecl.ParseException: Encountered "@" at
line 40, column 9.
Error while determining classes contained in
org/eclipse/milo/opcua/stack/core/util/TaskQueue.java Exception
oracle.aurora.sqljdecl.ParseException: Encountered "default" at line
343, column
Error while determining classes contained in
org/eclipse/milo/opcua/stack/core/types/DataTypeEncoding.java
Exception oracle.aurora.sqljdecl.ParseException: Encountered "default"
at line 39, column
Error while determining classes contained in
org/eclipse/milo/opcua/stack/core/types/OpcUaDefaultBinaryEncoding.java
Exception oracle.aurora.sqljdecl.ParseException: Encountered "@" at
line 61, column 13.
Error while determining classes contained in
org/eclipse/milo/opcua/stack/core/types/DataTypeDictionary.java
Exception oracle.aurora.sqljdecl.ParseException: Encountered "default"
at line 97, column
and so on and so on... error repeats, but reason is the same...

How Application looks like:
    package OPCUA.ORACLE;
    
    import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.OpcUaClient;
    import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.api.UaClient;
    import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.nodes.UaVariableNode;
    import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.Identifiers;
    import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.DataValue;
    import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.LocalizedText;
    import org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.NodeId;
    import static org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.types.builtin.unsigned.Unsigned.uint;
    
    import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
    
    public class OPCUA {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                // Create OPC UA client
                OpcUaClient client=OpcUaClient.create(
                        "opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:62541/milo",
                        endpoints ->
                            endpoints.stream()
                                .findFirst(),
                        configBuilder ->
                            configBuilder
                                .setApplicationName(LocalizedText.english("eclipse milo opc-ua client"))
                                .setApplicationUri("urn:eclipse:milo:examples:client")
                                .setRequestTimeout(uint(5000))
                                .build()
                    );
                // Connect to the server
                CompletableFuture<UaClient> future = client.connect();
                UaClient connectedClient = future.get();
    
                System.out.println("Connected to the OPC UA server.");
    
                // Read a value from a variable node
                NodeId nodeId = Identifiers.Server_ServerStatus_CurrentTime;
                UaVariableNode variableNode = connectedClient.getAddressSpace().getVariableNode(nodeId);
                DataValue value = variableNode.readValue();
                System.out.println("Value: " + value.getValue().getValue());
    
                // Disconnect the client
                client.disconnect().get();
                System.out.println("Disconnected from the OPC UA server.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

On the end I would like to state that I'm not a java developer at any point, so I'm totally green on those topics.
I would want to ask you, if you know what I might be doing wrong that stops me from loading JAR into Oracle Database and being able to run it.
Edit:
My pom.xml file looks like:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>OPCUA</groupId>
  <artifactId>ORACLE</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>ORACLE</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.milo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sdk-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.14-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
</project>

opc-ua-sdk pom.xml (i've added the exclude part in executions node for metadata):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.milo</groupId>
        <artifactId>milo</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.14-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>opc-ua-sdk</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <annotations.version>22.0.0</annotations.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.32</slf4j.version>
        <testng.version>6.11</testng.version>
        <mockito.version>2.25.1</mockito.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>dictionary-manager</module>
        <module>dictionary-reader</module>
        <module>sdk-client</module>
        <module>sdk-core</module>
        <module>sdk-server</module>
        <module>sdk-tests</module>
        <module>integration-tests</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- configuration inherited from pluginManagement -->
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <id>default-compile</id>
                          <configuration>
                              <!-- compile everything to ensure module-info contains right entries -->
                              <release>${java.version.jigsaw}</release>
                          </configuration>
                      </execution>
                      <execution>
                          <id>base-compile</id>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>compile</goal>
                          </goals>
                          <!-- recompile everything for target VM except the module-info.java -->
                          <configuration>
                              <excludes>
                                  <exclude>module-info.java</exclude>
                              </excludes>
                          </configuration>
                      </execution>
                  </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- configuration inherited from pluginManagement -->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- configuration inherited from pluginManagement -->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <X-SDK-Version>${project.version}</X-SDK-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeFilterFile>${basedir}/../findbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>sonatype-oss-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>

opc-ua-stack pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright (c) 2022 the Eclipse Milo Authors
  ~
  ~ This program and the accompanying materials are made
  ~ available under the terms of the Eclipse Public License 2.0
  ~ which is available at https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/
  ~
  ~ SPDX-License-Identifier: EPL-2.0
  -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.milo</groupId>
        <artifactId>milo</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.14-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>opc-ua-stack</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <bouncycastle.version>1.78.1</bouncycastle.version>
        <guava.version>33.0.0-jre</guava.version>
        <javassist.version>3.23.1-GA</javassist.version>
        <annotations.version>24.1.0</annotations.version>
        <netty.version>4.1.109.Final</netty.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.32</slf4j.version>
        <testng.version>6.9.10</testng.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>bsd-core</module>
        <module>bsd-generator</module>
        <module>bsd-parser</module>
        <module>bsd-parser-gson</module>
        <module>stack-client</module>
        <module>stack-core</module>
        <module>stack-server</module>
        <module>stack-tests</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                  <executions>
                      <execution>
                          <id>default-compile</id>
                          <configuration>
                              <!-- compile everything to ensure module-info contains right entries -->
                              <release>${java.version.jigsaw}</release>
                          </configuration>
                      </execution>
                      <execution>
                          <id>base-compile</id>
                          <goals>
                              <goal>compile</goal>
                          </goals>
                          <!-- recompile everything for target VM except the module-info.java -->
                          <configuration>
                              <excludes>
                                  <exclude>module-info.java</exclude>
                              </excludes>
                          </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    </executions>
                <!-- configuration inherited from pluginManagement -->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- configuration inherited from pluginManagement -->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- configuration inherited from pluginManagement -->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <X-Stack-Version>${project.version}</X-Stack-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                        <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeFilterFile>${basedir}/../findbugs-exclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Have you tried: building the Java application using the same version that the database uses; and using loadjava to load all the dependencies (including dependencies' dependencies, etc.) into the database before loading your application?

@MT0 ofcourse, i even tried to make it with normal JAR not Runnable JAR, it didnt helped. I guess it doesnt matter if its runnable or not, because of the way oracle executes the code (its not looking for an entry point of an app).

Do you have a file called module-info.java in your source? If so, you shouldn't and that would indicate you're building with a higher version than 8. It would be a good idea to post pom.xml formatted as code

@g00se i deleted it manually, but the referenced Eclipse Milo is having that too.
Ofcourse i will attach pom's.

@MT0 i just tried to compile one of the loaded classess from the opcua-sdk-client classes directly on a database, and it says that it didnt have the import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
So i guess, it might be the reason for some failure, however, the errors while loading JAR with loadjava differ from that compile try. Any idea how to load all the dependencies (including dependencies'dependencies, etc.) ?

Your pom indicates that you are using a java.version.jigsaw property.  Now you may have that property set to something else but that suggest you are using Java 9 (Jigsaw project) to compile.  This would be why you are getting issues with module-info even being present.  The embedded java version is 8 for Oracle 19c.  You should really be compiling and packaging with Java 8.  Look to change your project setups to leverage a Java 8 compiler.

@M.Rizzo i added a system variable to installed JDK and removed old one from Java Builder Path. I thought it will be enough, if it is not, i will try to search another option to force compiling using java 1.8.

I fear you're going to at the very least struggle to run that at 1.8. At least one of the many dependencies is likely to be higher. One of the (default version) crypto deps seems to be even Java 21.

@g00se I think you are right, however i just imported it using loadjava without errors. I changed the pom's as @M.Rizzo suggested and module-info class files dont appear now. However when i tried to compile it on a database i got:  14:46:08 Info: 28 java sources  compiled.  1138 java sources had errors on compile.  Last error message: Success with compilation error. And i think its about lack dependencie's deps.

Yes, loading that is one thing but you won't be able to run that without meeting the dependencies (26 jars on the classpath)

@g00se Thank you for your replies. Now i miss around 1130 classes that cant compile on database. Strange thing is that when i picked 30 random and tried to compile them i got an error: 15:13:38 Info: 1 java source had errors on compile.  Last error message: ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.
This error is really strange

13770 classes in the 'fat jar'

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
